# What post-apocalypse live-action/anime hybrid had the hero play a piano on a beach?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this film in the 90's, it was a hybrid live action and cartoon (manga style) set after a nuclear (atomic?) war.

The part that sticks in my head from the live action part was the hero (coming out after the bombs, in his radiation suit) finding a piano on a beach/rubble ground and playing a short tune on it. This melody recurred through the film.

In the cartoon part, there were Victorian style buildings and people, with flying whales going overhead.

I think a girl would turn up in the live action part & that triggered the switch to the cartoon parts, and she was then a character in that part of the story.

For some reason, I think this film was Australian in origin.

Comment: I have no idea, but I want to watch it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're thinking of [*In the Aftermath*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0206827/), a 1988 Australian film. The film combines footage of the 1985 Anime film [*Angel's Egg*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0208502/) with new live-action footage.

There isn't a lot of information about *In the Aftermath* on the Internet. *Angel's Egg* is a little better represented; it has [a Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel%27s_Egg) and [a Tvtropes page](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/AngelsEgg). The live-action story in *Aftermath* follows some soldiers working their way through a ruined industrial area following an apocalypse. They spot a little girl carrying a large egg, who is the same girl from the animated portions.

The two films have very different stories, even just considering the animated parts. The *Angel's Egg* dialog is in Japanese. *In the Aftermath* looks like it reused the visuals, but edited them into a new story with new english-language dialog.

*In the Aftermath* is available [in full on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z6ZBzLLjCX4). *Angel's Egg* is also [available in its original form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgO9AzAFAX0).

> the hero (coming out after the bombs, in his radiation suit) finding a piano on a beach/rubble ground and playing a short tune on it.

There is a section where one of the soldiers plays a tune on a piano. It's not outside, though. It takes place around 43 minutes in.

> In the cartoon part, there were Victorian style buildings and people, with flying whales going overhead.

That describes the animated portions. The giant flying fish part starts about 36 minutes into *Aftermath*.

Comment: That's exactly the one I was thinking of, thank you. Had tried all sorts of ccombinations on Google to try and track it down.